# Emulator freezes while downloading

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a simple application to download and play a music file. I made a code but when try to test it, the application freezes and shows **'Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock'** If anyone has an idea, would you please give me little advice? Below is my code.

By the way, the sample file I'm trying to download has about 9.1MB size.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        setDataSource("http://cfs.tistory.com/custom/blog/66/661632/skin/images/Believe.mp3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setDataSource(String path) throws IOException {        

    URL url = new URL(path);
    HttpURLConnection cn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    cn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    cn.setDoOutput(true);
    cn.connect();

    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/download/";
    String fileName = "Temp.wav";
    File file = new File(file_path);
    file.mkdir();

    InputStream is = cn.getInputStream();
    File output_file = new File(file, fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output_file);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int read = 0;

    while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0){
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    is.close();
    fos.close();

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(file_path+fileName);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();

}
```

}

** Modified: ** Justin taught me if I just put it on onCreate() then it causes a problem. Now I'm using a button with a thread but got another problem that says **only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views** and seems like it's happening at 'fos.close'. If anyone knows what to do, would you please help me?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv.setText(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/download/");

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread thread;
            Runnable r = new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        setDataSource("http://cfs.tistory.com/custom/blog/66/661632/skin/images/Believe.mp3");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                       
                }
            };
            thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.start();

        }

    });
}
```

** Error Messages: **

```
07-15 04:31:45.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(313): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method is blocking the UI Thread for an extended period and so Android is Force Closing the application.

Try launching the long running process in a background thread in the onCreateMethod() and then update the UI when its finished.

- http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html
- http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html
- http://www.androidacademy.com/1-tutorials/43-hands-on/115-threading-with-android-part1

The best way to learn about how to apply multi-threading is to actually view one of the google sample apps that uses it.  Here's a quote from the first link.

```
"We highly recommend reading the source code of Shelves to see how to 
 persist tasks across configuration changes and how to cancel them 
 properly when the activity is destroyed."
```

**Update**: You should move the media player back into the UI thread, and have the background thread run and then update the string that feeds the media player when it's finished.  You may need to refactor to use an Async Task and move the media player creation into the onPostExecute().  You may want to stop here and experiment with Async Task and see how the Shelves app does multi-threading.

You can find links to the Shelves application in the first URL that I posed above (near the bottom of the page).

Comment: Hi, Justin. Thanks for your reply. In this case, then would you let me know where I can put this 'setDataSource' method?

Comment: Thanks for your great help Justin. I now see it doesn't freeze my app but still has a problem of time-out. If you don't mind, would you help me little bit more? I'll upload the modified code on the main question soon in two mins.

Comment: I got it Justin. Thanks for your explanation. I'll now close this topic

Answer (score 0):

calling. setDataSource like this

In your activity make one handler to get the control when music file has been downloaded.

```
Handler h1 = new Handler(){
   public void handleMessage(Message msg){
      // put the check here to see 
   }
};

new Thread(new Runnable(){

 public void run(){
   // set your datasource here 

   // back to your handler

}
}){
}.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply success_anil. I actually made my own thread just right before and it seems solved the problem but now I encountered another problem that says "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." I added this onto the main question and want to ask you that if you don't mind, would you help me little bit more to solve this problem?

Comment: That's why I answered with using the handlers you can solve the problem better.... In the above code, inside run method do this.. hi.sendMessage(h1.obtainMessage()); and inside your handler's handleMessage check if the file has been downloaded... and use the file

Comment: Thank you for your answer again, anil. If possible, would you do me a favor? I tried to implement your code but it gives me syntax error one after another and seems little bit hard for me to fix. I'm really sorry to ask this could you make a complete code for me?

Comment: Sorry to ask you too much anil. As Justin mentioned, this topic seems done already. I appreciate your help!